# How to read the html contents in about: in Firefox browser?

Tags: html, firefox

I need a way to read the html contents displayed in about:*, like about:config, about:cache, etc and parse the results.

No problem in parsing the results. But I have found no way to read it's contents using any language except javascript

Answer (score 0):

**Background:**

The pages you're referring to (ex: about:*) are loaded from local config files.

**Solution 1: The "In Browser" solution**
Javascript works because its interacting with that loaded page (and browsers have pretty much standardized on javascript as their go-to language).  Its the only viable option from within the browser.

**Solution 2: Avoiding JavaScript**
If you're trying to access the data outside of the browser, it may be easier to access those files directly.

See [this page on loading configurations from Mozilla.org](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_configuration)

Comment: What about information in "about:cache?device=memory"? Does firefox also has information about memory cache service in disk?

Comment: @GT8 Unfortunately I can't help you there (did some poking around in the prefs.js but no go).  I would check the mozilla forums at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions.  Sounds like you might be digging a little deeper into the platform than a simple setting. Hopefully they can help!

Answer (score 0):

Just look for the file locations.
about:config is in `prefs.js`
at

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile name>
```